# Get Package Name/ApplicationId in Other pages

Tags: flutter

I want to implement rate and share button in my app so I am using `url_launcher` and here I want to put `url` of my app.
Currently it is working as

`url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.learncodeonline.lco";`

but I want this type

```
 url="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={packageName}"
```

Comment: fetch packageName,appname,version etc.. with "https://pub.dev/packages/package_info" @Pramod Yadav

Answer (score 0):

**Just call this function with package Name**

```
void shareAnyApp(String packageName) async {
    var url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageName";

    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    }
  }
```

**To Get Current App Package use [Package_info](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info)**

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
shareAnyApp(packageInfo.packageName );
```

Comment: main problem is getting  packageName in this method from build.gradle file

Comment: @PramodYadav see updaed ans